# What is wrong with this fake proof $e^i = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fake-proofs

$$e^{i} = e^{i2\pi/2\pi} = (e^{2\pi i})^{1/(2\pi)} = 1^{1/(2\pi )} = 1$$

Obviously, one of my algebraic manipulations is not valid.

Comment: @StefanHansen, you can elaborate (not because it  is insufficient but to make it worthy of being called answer.) a little and answer it .

Comment: The proof is exactly the same idea as $-1=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$. It is less obvious just because the "root" part is the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ power...

Comment: Or $1=1^{1/2}=(e^{i 2 \pi })^{1/2}= e^{i \pi} = -1$

Comment: @leonbloy When I first learnt of Euler's Identity, this was the first thing that came to mind. It is my favourite paradox (although not true) :D

Comment: As a complex power, the result of $1^{1/2\pi}$ is not $1$, but $e^{ki}$ where $k\in\Bbb Z\,.$

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As said in the comments, the expressions $(a^b)^c$ and $a^{bc}$ are in fact multivalued functions; they are *not* a uniquely determined complex number. A classic example of a multivalued function is the complex logarithm denoted by $\log(z)$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$. The complex logarithm $\log(z)$ is any complex number $w$ satisfying $e^w=z$ (which has several solutions, see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)), and hence $\log(z)$ gives rise to a whole set of complex numbers instead of just a single complex number.

Complex exponentiation such as $z^w$ for $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ is usually defined as
$$
z^w=\exp(w\log(z)),
$$
where $\log(z)$ is the complex logarithm, and hence this is also a multivalued function. I hope this sheds some light on the problems with doing manipulations on complex numbers as if they were real numbers. See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities) for other examples of identities which fail when using complex numbers as they were real numbers.

Comment: Then proofs of demoivire theorum is wrong ? And also the derivation of cubes root of unity ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add this here as the most general answer to this common problem in solving equations, a principle which the other answers do not cover:

When asked to solve for $y$, an equation of the form:

$$y=f(x)$$

(in your example $f(x)=e^i$)

The approach commonly taken is to solve by writing a sequence of **equivalent** equations working towards $y=\text{the desired answer}$, in your case as follows:

$y=e^{i}\\ y= e^{i2\pi/2\pi} \\y= (e^{2\pi i})^{1/(2\pi)}\\y = 1^{1/(2\pi )}\\y = 1$

> Then this method is only reliable if it is truthful to write **if and only if** between every consecutive pair of equivalent equations in sequence as follows:

$y=e^{i}\\\iff\\ y= e^{i2\pi/2\pi} \\\iff\\y= (e^{2\pi i})^{1/(2\pi)}\\\iff\\y = 1^{1/(2\pi )}\\\iff\\y = 1$

Due to the periodicity of complex powers, the $\iff$ statement is contradictory to the laws of arithmetic in various places in the above chain.