# Confused about complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am confused about something:
\begin{eqnarray}
    (e^{2 i \pi})^{0.5} = (e^{2 i \pi \cdot 0.5})= e^{i \pi}=-1
\end{eqnarray}
but
\begin{eqnarray}
     e^{2 i \pi}=1~ and~ 1^{0.5}=1 
\end{eqnarray}
where is my mistake??

thanks

Comment: The short version: if $z$ is complex, then $z^{0.5}$ is meaningless.

Comment: Note that just like every positive real number, 1 has two square roots: 1 and -1.

Comment: You have discovered multi-valued roots; but you knew about them already, right? Both +1 and -1 are square roots of +1.

Comment: 1^0.5=-1? I dont understand this

Comment: $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$.  (Well, the real roots, anyway!)  Also, $(-1)^2 = 1^2 = 1$.

Comment: Slightly longer version: If $z$ is complex, then $z^{0.5}$ is not a function.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, wouldn't that be true even over the reals? I mean $1^{.5} = \pm 1$, right? Or do we just define exponents as the positive root over the reals?

Comment: @k_g: Yes, it's true over the reals, too.  The way out is that we restrict $x$ to nonnegative real numbers in order to make $\sqrt{x}$ a function.  But with complex numbers it's customary to consider $\sqrt{z}$ a multi-valued function.

Comment: @JackM: Complaining that $z^{1/2}$ is meaningless for (non-real) complex $z$ is not to the point, because $\exp(2\pi\mathbf i)$ is actually real.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I've had profs who'd insist that $ e^{2 \pi i} $ is complex, and happens to be a complex number with a zero imaginary part. This context here is one where the distinction matters.

Comment: @JackM may have been pointing out, tersely, that while $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ has two values, $z^{0.5}$ is meaningless.

Comment: Another related post: [What is wrong with this fake proof $e^i = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281528)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's exactly as if you would write:

> I am confused about something: 
>   $$((-1)^2)^{0.5} = (-1)^{2\cdot 0.5} = (-1)^1 = -1$$
>   but
>   $$(-1)^2=1 \text{ and } 1^{0.5} = 1$$
>   where is my mistake??

Comment: LOL! Great minds think alike, I guess :)

Comment: This is **not** the same situation, because in the question everything that appears as base of an exponentiation is actually a positive real number, unlike $-1$ in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

When dealing with complex numbers, you no longer interchange radicals with fractional exponents, in the same way you did with positive real numbers.

If $x$ is real, $\sqrt[3]x$ denotes the principal cube root of $x$, and has only one value. In this way $8^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt[3]{8}$ mean the same thing.

But if we are doing algebra with complex numbers, and we wrote $5^{1/3}$, we would mean any solution to $z^3 - 5 = 0$.

So $1^{1/2}$ is defined as any solution to $z^2 - 1 = 0$. $z = 1$ and $z = -1$ are both solutions to this.

Comment: Would you also say that $e^{0.5}$ could stand for the negative number $-\sqrt e\,$?

Answer (score 7):

Exponentation $x^y$ can be unambiguously defined whenever $x$ is a positive real number, and $y$ is any complex number. The value is (per definition if you like) equal to $\exp(y\ln(x))$ where $\exp:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is the usual exponential function, which is well defined and well behaved. [Writing it using $e^z$ would give a circular definition here.]  But the rule $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ is *only valid when $y$ is real*; this is more strict than requiring $x^y$ to be real (as the question illustrates), which is the condition necessary for $(x^y)^z$ to be defined in the first place.

The proof that $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ when $x>0$ and $y$ are real is simple:
$$
  x^{yz}\stackrel{\rm def}=\exp(yz\ln(x))
= \exp(z\ln(x^y))\stackrel{\rm fed}=(x^y)^z
\qquad(x,y\in\Bbb R, x>0, z\in\Bbb C).
$$
This also shows that that a situation with $x^{yz}\neq(x^y)^z$ where both sides are defined but $y\notin\Bbb R$ must boil down to a similar but more basic situation involving $\ln$. Indeed the rule $y\ln(x)=\ln(x^y)$ is not valid for $y\notin\Bbb R$ even if the arguments to $\ln$ are both real:
$$\def\ii{\mathbf i}
  2\pi\ii=2\pi\ii\ln(e)\neq\ln(e^{2\pi\ii})=\ln(1)=0.
$$

---

Curiously, the failure of $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ when $y\notin\Bbb R$ does not dissuade people to [employ this very rule when trying to "define" such exressions as $\ii\,^\ii$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Computing_complex_powers). I find such attempts truly pathetic. There is no point in trying to define exponentiation beyond the case of positive real base, or integer exponent; one gains nothing but confusion.

Comment: +1 I was going to add that complex to the rational power $z^{n/d}$ is not meaningless, albeit having $d$ values, but on further thought about what you wrote, I see that such cases are much better stated as e.g. $\sqrt[d]{z^n}$, avoiding confusion.

Comment: Why do you find $i^i$ pointless, but not $\pi^\pi$?

Comment: @GFauxPas: Because $\pi$ is a positive real number, but $\mathbf i$ is not. There is not natural sense in which raising $\mathbf i$ to a non-integral power means anything.

Comment: "Multiplying $\pi$ by itself $\pi$ times" doesn't have an intuitive meaning either, though. But this is a derailment.

Comment: $\pi^\pi$ may be a strange number that you would never need, but it has a clear meaning. Take any exponential growth process; mark the time it takes to grow by a factor $\pi$ and then let it evolve $\pi$ times as long.

Answer (score 6):

Here, let me try and make an analogy that you might be able to understand simply. As stated in the comments, 1 has two square roots: 1 and -1. See why this is important below.

$$((-1)^{2})^{0.5} = (-1)^{(2 \times 0.5)} = (-1)^1 = -1$$

OR

$$((-1)^{2})^{0.5} = 1^{0.5} = \sqrt{1} = 1$$

Do you get it?