# $-1$ to the power of a irrational number

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, pi

According to Wolfram Alpha, $(-1)^\pi \approx -0.90 + 0.43i$.

But $\pi$ has proven to be irrational (we can't write $\pi$ in terms of a fraction $a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ integers) and, in the real numbers, a negative number raised to a fraction with even denominator is undefined*.

So why is $(-1)^\pi$ a complex number, if there is no even denominator?

*Of course there are exceptions, like $(-1)^{4/2} = (-1)^2 = 1$ and $(-1)^{6/2} = (-1)^3 = -1$, but consider that the numerator is not a multiple of the denominator.

Comment: Do you know how $(-1)^\pi$ is defined?

Comment: In the complex domain you don't have to have a rational exponent.  But if you don't, you'looking as a function with infinitely many possible values.

Answer (score 13):

This has to do with complex numbers.  $$(-1)^{\pi}=\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{\pi}=e^{i\pi^2}=\cos{\pi^2}+i\sin{\pi^2}$$
which is the value given by WolframAlpha.

However, since $-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$ for every integer $n,$ there are actually infinitely many values of $(-1)^\pi.$  With complex numbers, exponentiation works differently from the way it does with real numbers.

Comment: You mean $\cdots=\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{\pi}=\cdots$ I guess.

Comment: @drhap  Of course I do thanks.  I struggled with the MathJax, and by the time I got it to accept anything, I  wasn't looking too closely any more, I guess.

Comment: You need to justify that $(e^{i\pi})^\pi=e^{i\pi^2}$. In general, we don't have a rule $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ for complex numbers.

Comment: @user1551 Even when $z$ is real?

Comment: The rule $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ fails even when $z$ is real. The problem is that neither $(x^y)^z$ nor $x^{yz}$ are unambigusously defined. In case $x>0$ and $z$ is real, both $x^y$ and $x^{yz}$ are well-defined, but $(x^y)^z$ is still not. In the OP's case, as you said, $(-1)^\pi$ can assume infinitely many values. In fact, $$(-1)^\pi=\exp(\pi\log(-1))=\exp(\pi(i\pi+2in\pi))=e^{i\pi^2}e^{2in\pi^2}$$ but the value of $e^{2in\pi^2}$ varies with $n$. You may see [Marc van Leeuwen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105203) in another thread about the applicability of the rule $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$.

Comment: @user1551 All I meant was that $e^{i\pi^2}$ is one of the possible values of $(-1)^\pi.$

Answer (score 9):

For complex numbers, we define $a^b = \exp(b \log a)$.  Of course $\log$ is "multivalued", so $a^b$ is also multivalued.  Even $(-1)^{1/3}$ has three values, two of them are non-real.  In case of $(-1)^\pi$, there are infinitely many values, all non-real.

Wolfram has a system of choosing a "principal value" in these cases, and it uses the logarithm with imaginary part in $(-\pi,\pi]$.  So the principal value of $\log(-1)$ is $i\pi$.  And the principal value of $(-1)^\pi$ is $\exp(\pi\log(-1)) =
\exp(i\pi^2) = \cos(\pi^2)+i\sin(\pi^2)\approx -0.90 - i 0.43$.