# Is $e^\pi$ equal to $(e^{i\pi})^{-i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

Fermat's Library [tweeted](https://twitter.com/fermatslibrary/status/1206575467014348800) five hours ago that $e^\pi$ can be proved to be transcendental as follows. Let $A=-1$ and $B=-i$. Then $A$ and $B$ are algebraic numbers, $A\ne0,1$ and $B$ is not rational. Therefore, by Gelfond-Schneider theorem,
$$A^B=e^\pi=(e^{i\pi})^{-i}=(-1)^{-i}\tag{1}$$
is a transcendental number.

The same equality $(1)$ is also mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), but I am confused because an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105203) on this site stated that the rule $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ is valid only when $x>0$ and $y$ is real. Does the rule really apply here? Is the proof in the aforementioned tweet valid?

Comment: The usual approach is to work with $i^i$ which is , if we use the proper branch , $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Since this is transcendental, $e^\pi$ is transcedental as well. We can use Gelfond-Schneider here because we get a transcendental number for every possible branch. So, we can be sure that $e^{\pi}$ is actually transcendental.

Comment: Look at the explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem#Statement)  Not everyone agrees with the position taken in the answer you cite.  I well remember that an early exercise in Lars Ahlfors' complex analysis book is "Show that there are infinitely many values of $i^i$ and they are all real and positive."  Ahlfors was a Fields medalist, specializing in complex analysis.

Comment: See [Gelfond's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant), mentioned by saulspatz. Wikipedia is (perhaps) a better reference than twitter.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. *"...then $\color{red}{\text{any}}$ value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number"*. This is much better than the over-simplified statement in the tweet!

Comment: Better than "any value of" would be "every value of" or "all values of … are", in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Just because an identity does not hold generically, does not mean that there are no coincidences where it seems to work anyway.

Having chosen a branch of the logarithm, we may write the [complex exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases) 
$$  (-1)^{-\mathrm{i}} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \ln(-1)}  $$
and proceed from there.

If we do not wish to choose a branch of the logarithm, we instead write
$$  (-1)^{-\mathrm{i}} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} (\ln(-1) + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k)}  $$
for some choice of integer $k$ (which choice is equivalent to a choice of branch).  Then we can evaluate $\ln(-1)$ on any branch, for instance $\ln(-1) = \mathrm{i} \pi$.  And finally, \begin{align*}
-\mathrm{i} (\ln(-1) + 2 \pi \mathrm{i} k) &= -\mathrm{i}(\mathrm{i} \pi + 2\pi \mathrm{i}k)  \\
&= \pi + 2 \pi k  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So
$$  (-1)^{-\mathrm{i}} = \mathrm{e}^{\pi + 2 \pi k}  \text{,}  $$
where the choices of $k$ correspond to different choices of branch of logarithm in defining the complex exponential.  If we choose the branch with $k = 0$, we recover the claimed identity.