# $e^{2 \pi\cdot i / 3} = (e^{2 \pi\cdot i}) ^{2/ 3} = 1^{2/3} = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to calculate the 3rd cyclotomic polynomial $\phi_3$.

So according to the definition we have: $\phi_3 = (x - e^{2 \pi\cdot i / 3})(x - e^{2 \pi\cdot i \cdot 2/ 3})$

---

I seem to have a basic misunderstanding of polar coordinates:

$e^{2 \pi\cdot i / 3} = (e^{2 \pi\cdot i}) ^{2/ 3} = 1^{2/3} = 1$ which is clearly wrong. But why can't you do that? It follows the formulas we had...

Comment: e^2pi/3 = (e^2pi)^(2/3) why? (e^x)^y = e^xy

Comment: Also, $(a^{b})^{c}=a^{bc}$ is  not valid for complex numbers.

Comment: This is the same error as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281528/42969 – can we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes it does answer my question, thanks